# How to Derive a Core Data Attribute Key from an NSManagedObject Property?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, key, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to retrieve the key of a Core Data entity's attribute directly from the property of the corresponding `NSManagedObject`? This would remove the need for reliance on string-based ('stringly-typed') code for some situations, thereby reducing the risk of error.

For example, I would want to replace the following:

`fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdDate", ascending: false)]`

...with something more like this:

`fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: exampleNSManagedObject.createdDate.key, ascending: false)]`

I know that `.defaultSortDescriptors` can be used to achieve some of this, but only for a fixed attribute. I also know that `.entity.attributesByName.keys` can be used to get the list of keys, but I haven't established a way to then automatically isolate the relevant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the #keyPath string expression what you are looking for?  From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective-c_runtime_features_in_swift):

> You use the #keyPath string expression to create compiler-checked keys and key paths that can be used by KVC methods

For example:

`fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(ExampleNSManagedObject.createdDate), ascending: false)]`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. No more stringly-typed code in my Core Data sorts & searches. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I updated your answer with an example, just to tie it closer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you could write an Extension to `NSManagedObject` containing a function which would take a human-written string and return the best match among `.entity.attributesByName.keys`, and this would solve the problem as you've stated it.

But a better way is to use a tool which will automatically generate such key constants from your data model.  Check out [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator), an open-source "pro" replacement for the Core Data code generation which is built into Xcode.  Among its features is generating an enum like this for each entity:

```
public enum MyEntityAttributes: String {
    case createdDate = "createdDate"
    case foo = "foo"
    case bar = "bar"
}
```

and then the key string you want can be accessed as `MyEntityAttributes.foo`.